# Puppet :: filebucket and purge

Tags: puppet

I am attempting to do an ensure -> purge on a small number of very large files.  The files exist on a different partition than filebucket (and its partition is very small).  I would like to avoid any partition resizing if at all possible.  Is there any way to skip filebucket archival when doing a purge on files/directories?  (Don't worry - if the result is not what I expect, I have options to restore the previous state of the machine since it's a VM.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep a file from being stored in the filebucket prior to removal, set the `backup` parameter to `false`.

```
file {
    '/opt/data/huge-file1':
        ensure => absent,
        backup => false,
}
```

As an aside, I assume you're using `ensure => directory` with `purge => true`, because `purge` is not a valid `ensure` value.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I meant exactly what you said. :-)